# Android Studio - Github : The requested URL returned error 403

Tags: android, github

I am not able to push my Android Project to Github. I keep getting the the following error when I try to push the changes from my Android project to Github:

[image]

I have followed the correct procedure to add my Android Project to Github. I am the sole owner of the project. I am able to create a repository in my local directory and commit changes to it, but I am not able to push the changes to the Github repository. I keep getting the "The requested URL returned error: 403". Please advise me if I have missed a trick. 
Thanks

Comment: Assuming this is Android Studio: 403 means that you're not authorised. Check that you've entered your password, or even better: switch to SSH instead of using HTTPS.

Comment: Are you using Mac?